# Current Status from Area 51

Tags: discussion, beta

Not sure how many folks know that Area 51 maintains stats for all the sites in Beta as they work towards graduation.  To get out of Beta a site usually needs at least 4/5 stats in the green.  Our site is still pretty new and most of the downside is related to traffic, which we have already been talking about.  But, it's nice to see things laid out plainly.

[image: screenshot of stats page]

(For up-to-date stats, see [the page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43029/amateur-radio).)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reference. To complete this picture though, the blog post (below) discusses what these numbers mean; or more precisely, what these numbers ***don't*** mean.

[**Does this site have a chance of succeeding?**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/)

Following raw statistics can be tricky business and, as it turns out, these numbers don't reveal as much about the *health* of a site as you would expect. Long story short, don't watch your numbers too closely; that's *our* problem. Your job right now is to focus on your site to create a fantastic end-user experience and collection of content for everyone who comes through here.

Here's a related blog post that inevitably comes up in relation to this topic:

[**When Will My Site Graduate?**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/)

Enjoy!